# Unable run Angular material example in plunker

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I created one sample project using Angular Material example in plunker. its worked fine till yesterday today its not working.

Even Angular Material example is not working. can you please point me into right direction.

I was getting same error as original Angular material plunker error.

```
Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'PlunkerMaterialModule'
    Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'PlunkerMaterialModule'
        at d (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zone.js/0.7.2/zone.min.js:1:10303)
        at syntaxError (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
        at eval (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15596:40)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15594:49)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15507:52)
        at eval (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15580:72)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15565:49)
        at JitCompiler._loadModules (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27000:70)
        at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26973:36)
        at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26902:37)
        at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4568:25)
        at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4554:21)
        at execute (https://run.plnkr.co/preview/cj8fyb96l00063c5srholji8p/main.ts!transpiled:108:65)
    Error loading https://run.plnkr.co/preview/cj8fyb96l00063c5srholji8p/main.ts
        at d (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zone.js/0.7.2/zone.min.js:1:10303)
        at syntaxError (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
        at eval (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15596:40)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15594:49)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15507:52)
        at eval (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15580:72)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15565:49)
        at JitCompiler._loadModules (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27000:70)
        at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26973:36)
        at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26902:37)
        at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4568:25)
        at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4554:21)
        at execute (https://run.plnkr.co/preview/cj8fyb96l00063c5srholji8p/main.ts!transpiled:108:65)
    Error loading https://run.plnkr.co/preview/cj8fyb96l00063c5srholji8p/main.ts
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/GKuQv2GnExGPEE3iWynF?p=preview
https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`md` prefix was announced as deprecated in 2.0.0-beta.11 and seems now(**2.0.0-beta.12**) it is removed. We should use `mat` instead.

So instead of importing:

```
MdTabsModule
```

and

```
<md-tab-group class="demo-tab-group">
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">
```

use

```
MatTabsModule
```

and

```
<mat-tab-group class="demo-tab-group">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">
```

**[Plunker Example@2.0.0-beta.12](https://plnkr.co/edit/b5uJEm6zcmvG888pETqh?p=preview)**

Or you can set angular-material version to @2.0.0-beta.11 explicitly:

```
'@angular/material': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.11/bundles/material.umd.js',
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zCnWBz9XifFKky2KcGlo?p=preview)**

I also advice you to see all examples here

- https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/demo-app

Comment: Thx. you are a life saver !!

Comment: @Jonnysai Here are all the other breaking changes in `2.0.0-beta.12`: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes