# export materialmodule was not found in angular/material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I installed https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-tour module and integrated as per guidelines but I am getting `export materialmodule was not found in angular/material`  and other same kind of errors on npm start or build. what could be the issue here and how can it be resolved. I already have checked the packages and they all are installed.

Thanks

Comment: Add `"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.10",` to your package json

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607524/unable-run-angular-material-example-in-plunker/46607819#46607819

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import Angular Material in project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166844/how-to-import-angular-material-in-project)

Comment: Maybe not dup, but related

Comment: This way I will end up with lot of major changes in my project I guess

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MaterialModule` depreciated in version **2.0.0-beta.3** and it was removed completely in version **2.0.0-beta.11**. See this [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for more details. Please go through the breaking changes.

> MaterialModule has been removed and is no longer available. As noted
>   in the changelog for beta.3, an aggregate module like MaterialModule
>   prevents tools from being able to treeshake unused components and
>   modules.

Also, with `2.0.0-beta.11` and greater, update your angular version to `4.4.3` or greater. Material `2.0.0-beta.11` depends on `4.4.3` or greater. Feom the CHANGELOG:

> **Breaking changes** 
>   Angular Material now requires Angular 4.4.3 or greater

Now you have two options:

1. **Dowgrade to `2.0.0-beta.10`**
2. ‎**Include individual material component modules in order to use them in your app.**

In second case,

```
import { MatSelectModule, MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';

...
imports: [ 
    ....
    MatSelectModule,
    ‎MatButtonModule
]
```

Lastly, remeber that since `2.0.0-beta.12` the `Md` prefix has been removed and you should use `Mat` prefix everywhere. From the CHANGELOG of `2.0.0-beta.11`:

> For beta.11, we've made the decision to deprecate the "md" prefix
>   completely and use "mat" moving forward. This affects all class names,
>   properties, inputs, outputs, and selectors (CSS classes were changed
>   back in February). The "md" prefixes will be removed in the next beta
>   release.

And from the CHANGELOG of `2.0.0-beta.12`:

> **Breaking Changes** 
>   All "md" prefixes have been removed.

See this working [**StackBlitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-11-fsyxmh?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) with individual material modules and using `Mat` prefix.

‎

Answer (score 5):

Well, the module [is gone](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta11-carapace-parapet-2017-09-21). Either you downgrade to `"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.10"` as @yurzui suggested.

Or -- **better** -- just don't use it in your AppModule. Just import the specific modules of interest, like [`MatButtonModule`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecation-of-md-prefix) (because even `MdButtonModule` is deprecated).

Comment: `Or -- better` then he has to change `md` to `mat` prefix everywhere in that ngx-tour package https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-tour/blob/master/ngx-tour-md-menu/src/tour-step-template.component.ts#L11

Comment: @yurzui I am not a contributor of that package. Feel free to post a pull request if you will.

Answer (score 0):

Replace in imports MdCardModule, MdMenuModule, MdToolbarModule, MdIconModule etc  if not all but most of them are changed and keyword **Md** is replaced **Mat** keywork i.e MatSelectModule, MatCardModule, MatMenuModule etc.
Thanks for the above answers. They had reasons, while I have a short answer.. Cheers.