# How can I deal with that, If I need all the components in Angular Material 2?

Tags: angular-material2

According to the offical document,"MaterialModule" was removed as of 2.0.beta-11. In my old project I have to import all the submodule one by one. That is really a tedious work. How can I improve this to import all the modules I need.

```
import{MatListModule,MatInputModule,MatSlideToggleModule,
MatSelectModule,MatDialogModule,MatToolbarModule,
MatCardModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Comment: See this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46629351/1791913 ... and you can copy the code from `material.module.ts` file in this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-11-fsyxmh?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not. The CHANGELOG.md for version `2.0.0-beta.11 carapace-parapet (2017-09-21)` says:

> `MaterialModule` has been removed. (cf1ece0) (#6803) See the deprecation notice from beta.3 for more information. -- [Source](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta11-carapace-parapet-2017-09-21)

---

You have to enumerate the modules of interest manually.

Comment: Can I revert to an old version of Angular Material 2, which has the MaterialModule?

Comment: @edisonxue Yes, it is an option, but why would you do that? The release version will unlikely go back to having `MaterialModule`. Do you want to live with the bugs of `beta10` forever?

Comment: @edisonxue it is literally a few minutes of work to list all the modules you need. And it is a one time exercise...

Comment: ok，I will try to enumerate that.