# Template Parse Error: 'mat-sidenav-container' is not a known element

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular/material2 and I'm unsure of what I'm missing from trying to follow the documentation on `sidenav`.

In my AppComponent, I would like to display a sidenav and I've implemented as follows:

app.component.tss

```
import {
    NgModule,
    Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSidenavContent,
    MatSidenav
} from '@angular/material';
import {
    BrowserAnimationsModule
} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatSidenav
    ],
    exports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatSidenav
    ]
})
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
}
```

app.component.html

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<mat-sidenav-container>

</mat-sidenav-container>
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
        Welcome to {{ title }}!
    </h1>
    <nav>
        <a routerLink="/clients">Clients</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet>

    </router-outlet>

</div>]
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-sidenav-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message
```

What am I missing in my code?

Comment: import `MatSidenavContent`  module

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka, It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer from Sajeetharan was not working with newer versions of angular material.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46629351/):

> MaterialModule was deprecated in version 2.0.0-beta.3 and it was
>   removed completely in version 2.0.0-beta.11...

So, to fix the issue :

**On post 2.0.0-beta.3**:

```
import {
  MatSidenavModule,
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  exports: [MatSidenavModule],
  imports: [
    MatSidenavModule
  ],
})
```

**And in older versions**:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MaterialModule
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to import **`import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';`** in app.module.ts

```
imports: [    
    MaterialModule 
  ]
```

Since [`material module`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628211/export-materialmodule-was-not-found-in-angular-material/46629351#46629351) has been depreciated, With Angular latest version you need to use

```
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
```

Answer (score 11):

Angular 9 implementation

```
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

imports: [MatSidenavModule]
```